# Media queries work on browser but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, nuxt.js

I have a media query for Iphone X as following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 374px) and (max-width: 376px) and (min-height: 811px) and (max-height: 812px) {
  .welcome-banner {
    background-image: url('~assets/images/landing/welcome-banner-iphonex.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: calc(110vh - 64px);
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, but it does not in the mobile itself.
I do have the viewport tag on the meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: try with mobile screen wider than 374px. Min width measn, all of the screens smaller than that will be ignored

Comment: same with min height

Comment: That media query is way too specific, I would check here: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/iphonex/ Also, trying to target a specific device isn't probably the best way to go - aim for an average screen size for mobile devices.

Comment: (min-width: 374px) and (max-width: 376px) ??? Seems like your rules are a bit too specific.

Answer (score 0):

your query seems right but make sure it really is what this device you are testintg needs. you can get the correct cross-browser @media (width) and @media (height) values by logging the following to the console with javascript:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
console.log(w,h);
```

also recheck the `initial-scale` meta and zoom, they might be messing up your devices viewport.

Also, that query is very very specific. If you only - and i mean only - want to target this device then that is ok but it might be better to gi for more global queries, I usually target 320 and 767 (smaller than old Ipads) and maybe 480 inbetween if necessary.